# Python - Json: append element

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to add a element to a json file, but i can add it to the level 4 of the file (LogDetails), however, it works for level 3 (Logs).

I'm all new to Python and i can seem to figure this out, can someone help? :-)

```
import json

#Normaly loaded from a json file, but inserted here to make the exampel more simple - i hope :)
jsonfile = {
    "Job": {
        "id": "",
        "LoggingData": {
            "Logs":[{
                "LogDetails": [{
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}

def AddToJson(new_data,jsondata=""):
    print("jsondata type:", type(jsondata))
    if "LogDetails" in jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"]:
        print("Joy - Found LogDetails") 
        jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"]["LogDetails"].append(new_data)
    else:
        for sub in jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"]:
            print("Value of sub:"+str(sub))
        jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"].append(new_data)

    return(jsondata)

DataToAddToExistingJson = {"Step id": 1, "Step name": "Test"}

NewJsonfile =AddToJson(new_data=DataToAddToExistingJson,jsondata=jsonfile)
print ("NewJsonfile type:",type(NewJsonfile))
print ("NewJsonfile value:",NewJsonfile)
```

Output:

```
jsondata type: <class 'dict'>
Value of sub:{'LogDetails': [{}]}
NewJsonfile type: <class 'dict'>
NewJsonfile value: {'Job': {'id': '', 'LoggingData': {'Logs': [{'LogDetails': [{}]}, {'Step id': 1, 'Step name': 'Test'}]}}}
PS C:\>
```

I would have expected it to find the lowest level of the dict named LogDetails, but it seems to ignore it.

Wanted output for first run:

```
{
    "Job": {
        "id": "",
        "LoggingData": {
            "Logs": [{
                "LogDetails": [{
                    "Step id": 1,
                    "Step name": "Test"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

and the afterwards something like this:

```
{
    "Job": {
        "id": "",
        "LoggingData": {
            "Logs": [{
                "LogDetails": [{
                    "Step id": 1,
                    "Step name": "Test"
                }, {
                    "Step id": 2,
                    "Step name": "Test"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't work with json. Work with data. Then turn that data _into_ JSON only at the very last possible moment where you need a string.

Answer (score 0):

`jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"]` in your example is a list of dictionaries so the first condition is `False` that's why else comes into play and adds your data to the `Logs` list.

If you want it to make it work in your example, you should check it that way

```
if "LogDetails" in jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"][0]:
    ...
```

then the first condition would be `True`.
But it might break if `Logs` would be an empty list (since this is not clear from your question), so you have to check if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

> ```py
>     if "LogDetails" in jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"]:
>         jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"]["LogDetails"].append(new_data)
> ```

This would have worked as intended if your initial `jsonfile` looked like

```py
jsonfile = {
    "Job": {
        "id": "",
        "LoggingData": {
            "Logs":{"LogDetails": [{}]} ## NOT [{"LogDetails": [{}]}]
        }
    }
}
```

However, what you have is *`..."Logs":[{"LogDetails": [{}]}]...`*; so, *`jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"]`* is a **list** (from which items can be accessed with [indices, not keys](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#dictionary-keys-vs-list-indices)), so you can't check in it for *`"LogDetails"`* which is a **key** in the dictionary that is the first item in said list (i.e., **`jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"][0]`**).

To add `new_data` to the first dictionary in `Logs`, you should change that `if` block to

```py
    if "LogDetails" in jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"][0]:
        print("Joy - Found LogDetails") 
        jsondata["Job"]["LoggingData"]["Logs"][0]["LogDetails"].append(new_data)
```

Use **`...["Logs"][-1]...`** (instead of *`...["Logs"][0]...`*) if you want to add `new_data` to the *last* dictionary in `Logs`. [Ofc, it won't make a difference if `Logs` has only one item.]

<sub>Btw, you could also use [`isinstance`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/isinstance) and [`.setdefault`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/setdefault) [or even just [`try...except`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exception-handling)] to check for and ensure your data structure.</sub>